# Wpf RichtextBox: Access the fontfamily, font style, font weight from the pasted text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created a user control `TextEditor` using `Richtextbox` .But I am not able to access the font family, font color, font style of the text which I paste in the `Richtextbox`.
How can I access these font properties?
Please someone help me.

Comment: Can you please show us some code what you've tried so far?

Comment: I am trying to access these property in   DataObject.AddPastingHandler(richtextBox, MyPasteCommand);

Comment: I am able to access the text but not font properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RichTextBox control has a property called [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is a type of [FlowDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Use this then to access the text properties you require.

You can find the list of properties [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hope it helps.